# How can i validate the uploaded file name using Lavavel standard functions?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm not sure whether it is useful to check for inserted malicious code, but I would like to implement it nevertheless.

I want check the file name string with some Laravel validation, without php specifc functions, if such is possible.

Here is my code snippet:

```
$valiadateResult = Validator::make
        (
            $inReq->all(),
            [
                'atitle' => 'required',
                'keyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
                'gkeyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
                'up' => 'nullable|alpha_num|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp3,pdf|max:100000',
                'intro' => 'max:255',
                'full' => 'max:2000',
            ]
        );
```

So the `up` part is file validate, but it does not check the file name.
I try it, but the alpa_num does not work in this case.

So is there a solution for this using some Laravel function, or should I just use some PHP logic myself to validate, or do you think it is not necessary to validate such input ?

Comment: normally in development the file name doesn't matter, it gets renamed and then saved.

Comment: good point, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another fileds called `filename` in inputs and rules.

```
$filename = $request->file('up')->getClientOriginalName();
$allInput = $inReq->all();
$allInput['filename'] = $filename;
$valiadateResult = Validator::make
        (
            $allInput,
            [
                'atitle' => 'required',
                'keyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
                'gkeyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
                'up' => 'nullable|alpha_num|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp3,pdf|max:100000',
                'filename' => 'alpha_num',
                'intro' => 'max:255',
                'full' => 'max:2000',
            ]
        );
```

And you will get error with filename

Comment: thank you, it's almost worked :) 
just the `alpha_num` dose not like it, but the `regex` with a pattern, it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

1. Create custom validation rule class, for example `Filename`, and put it at path `app/Rules/Filename.php`.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class Filename implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if (!($value instanceof UploadedFile) || !$value->isValid()) {
            return false;
        }

        return preg_match('/^[\pL\pM\pN]+$/u', $value->getClientOriginalName()) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute name is invalid.';
    }
}
```

2. In your request rules add this custom rule like this:

```php
use App\Rules\Filename;

$valiadateResult = Validator::make(
    $inReq->all(),
    [
        'atitle' => 'required',
        'keyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
        'gkeyw' => 'max:255|alpha_num',
        'up' => ['nullable', new Filename, 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp3,pdf', 'max:100000'],
        'intro' => 'max:255',
        'full' => 'max:2000',
    ]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Additionally you can use "File" validation.

The field under validation must be a successfully uploaded file.

```
'up' => 'file|nullable|alpha_num|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,mp3,pdf|max:100000',
```

Comment: Thanks your help, but is not worked, the `alpha_num` throw an error, an if change it to `regex` it make error too.